# Testing a specific element using json POST in phpunit laravel-4

Tags: php, json, laravel-4, phpunit

I'm trying to test if a "name" is actually inserted into my controller.

I created this test to check for the "name":

```
  public function testStoreName()
{
    $json = '{"name":"FOO", "address":"fubar City", "nickname":"fubar"}';
     $post = $this->action('POST', 'FooController@store', null, array(), array(), array(), $json);
     $output= json_decode($this->client->getResponse()->getContent());
     $output->name;



     if($output->name != "")
     {
         echo "Test Passed\n\n";
     }

     elseif($output->name == "")
     {
        echo "Name cannot be null";
     }

  //      $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());
}
```

But when I alter the $json and set "name": ""; I get errors. I want it to say that "name cannot be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
   public function testStoreName()
       {
            $json = '{"name":"FOO", "address":"fubar City", "nickname":"fubar"}';
            $jsonDecode = json_decode($json, true);
            $name = $jsonDecode['name'];
            $post = $this->action('POST', 'FooController@store', null, array(), array(), array(), $json);

            $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());

            $output= json_decode($this->client->getResponse()->getContent());

            $this->assertEquals($name, $output->name, 'Name incorrect'); 

        }
```

The code above decoes the json string and we put the 'name' element into `$name` and we do an `assertEquals()` to compare the json string 'name' that we specified towards the actual 'name' content that is being inputted into the controller.